# How to copy files from dir and append date to filename?

Tags: linux, bash, date, cp

I'm trying to copy files from one directory to another and append current date to this filename. The script look like this

```
#!/bin/bash

echo 'Move to homedir'
cd $HOME

echo 'Copy .txt files'
NOW=$(date +"%d%m%Y")

for FILENAME in *.txt
do
        cp "${FILENAME}" "/newdir/${FILENAME}${NOW}"
done
```

This generates an error because date is appended after file extension, like this

> file1.txt10082013

How to avoid that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try extracting the extension and renaming the file:

```
NAME="${FILENAME%.*}"
EXT="${FILENAME##*.}"

cp "${FILENAME}" "/newdir/${NAME}${NOW}.${EXT}"
```

Comment: Thanks, what are these %% and ## after filename?

Comment: @Matkrupp They delete portions of the string. See more at [tldp](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html).

Comment: Ok, thanks, I tried it but it generates an error saying: cp: cannot create regular file `/newdir/file109082013.txt': No such file or directory

Comment: @Matkrupp It probably means `/newdir` doesn't exist

Comment: Yes, I found the reason for this, changed "/newdir/" to "$HOME/newdir" and now it was pointing to the right directory. Thanks for this!